# How to write a program that creates 2 parent processes and one child for each?

Tags: c

I'm not sure what does this code do.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        int pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("child process \n");
            printf("Child pid id [%d], parent pid is [%d]\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
        } else if(pid>0)
        {
            int stats;
            wait(&stats);
            printf("parent process \n");
            printf("Child pid id [%d], parent pid is [%d]\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I call `fork()` and assign it's value to variabe `pid`. Then we go to `int stats`, next line returns `pid=0`, then the program displays child process and then the parent process. It works pretty nice, but only when `i<1`. I thought that it is possible to do the same thing once again, but it's strange. `fork()` creates a new child process, so if it is used only once, if should create a child process, which parent is an IDE. Why am I wrong and what should I change to make 2 parents and 1 child for each, basically 4 processes?

Comment: What do you mean by _"make 2 parents and 1 child for each"_? A process can only have one parent process. Also in the parent branch of the if-statement: The `pid` holds to id of the newly created child and `getppid` will return the id of the parent of your main process (i.e. the grand parent of your newly created process)

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you mean by "2 parents". In any case, you need to return the child so that they do not loop again:

```
        printf("Child pid id [%d], parent pid is [%d]\n", (int) getpid(), (int) getppid());
        return 0;
```

Otherwise you will have the children spawning other processes.

Comment: I mean sth like this. Let's say we have a process called L1 (main program). Firstly it creates a child L2 with pid 10, we print this pid and then create another process (child of L2) with pid 11, then the program displays ```child pid is [11], parent pid is [10]```After that we go back to main function and create a child od main function called L3 with pid 20 and for L3 process we create child called L5 with pid 21. Then the program prints ```child pid is [21], parent pid is [20]```